# CloudFlare SSL certificate is a good solution?

Tags: https, security-certificate, cloudflare

I need to put an SSL certificate on a website in wordpress. It does not store any confidential information. I just want to gain some advantage in google ranking.

I have a free account on cloudflare. Their service ssl flexibe works for this?

I was also looking: letsencrypt.org there any difference between the services. Or both work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

SSL is available on all CloudFlare plan levels, including FREE.  Flexible SSL will create a secure connection between your site visitors and CloudFlare, but the connection between CloudFlare and your origin will not be secure.

You can learn more about the SSL offerings here:

https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/

Answer (score 1):

Letsencrypt is more like for developer and web programmer, if you have chosen WordPress just for blogging purpose, then I will say go with the cloudflare, because it is easy to setup for a lifetime.

Cloudflare is popular and widely used, but it does not mean, they are the best. For full encryption and security, you have to buy paid service.

> Their service ssl flexibe works for this?

Yes, I used that in past. But now I am using [Google Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/custom-domain.html) which gives me free SSL, but it is not for wordpress, it works great for static website.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare offers a dedicated SSL cert for $5 a month vs. their free shared certs. That may seem expensive, but if you go with Let's encrypt, their free certs expire in 3 months. After renewing your cert a few times, you may gladly want to pay the $5.

Cpanel has modules for Let's encrypt and Comodo, which offer free certs and auto renews every two months so that is a good solution for blogging websites. Certbot can be installed on dedicated servers and does the same thing.

For E-commerce websites, I would suggest you pony-up the money to get a real cert, but for a blogging website, I think Cloudflare's "full SSL" open would be sufficient. You would simply need a self-signed cert on your server and you would be all set. The "Flexible SSL" option is for lazy or incompetent people IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about CloudFlare certs. I use LetsEncrypt for my pro bono clients.

LetsEncrypt offers free certs that are good for three months only. They are easy to install and renew but, again, must be renewwed every three months.

I prefer to use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to do this. It's much easier and stable than going through LetsEncrypt.

You can use them for up to 100 (or is it 200?) alternate names but there is no wildcard.

Of course, they work the same as any other certificate that only offers site ownership verification.

Comment: Can you use them on cpanel? I mean LetsEncrypt

Comment: @OlanrewajuT I never use cpanel, or any of those types of things, so I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

It is good but Cloudflare can be a pain. I would say, it is very good, it saves a lot of bandwirth and protect your website for absolutely NO COST at all. But it can show problems on following things;

- Feature "Railgun" misbehves with many hosts, if you turn it on, then your site will start showing 501 error. It took me ages to find out that it was railgul which shut my site down.
- If your Host changes your IP for security reasons, your website will be down until you add your new IP manually. This can be a pain when it happens late at night and you realize it in the morning.
- Sometimes, adding to much Cloudflare apps can slowdown your website.

Despite these problems, i would still recommand CloudFlare as it is the best way to secure your website from DDoS attacks.